# How to change part of url browser witouth reload the page?

Tags: javascript

I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/activar_cuenta/5sadaaeasdas
```

how change my url to `http://localhost:4200/` witouth reload the page? only change the browser url.

thanks

Comment: Are you use Angular or Pure Js?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.history.pushState(null, '', '/');
```